# Is it possible to completely go into fullscreen?

Tags: 3d-view

I have hidden everything except the top header with the menus. Is there a way to hide that? Would scripting this require a lot of work ?

Edit: 
 thanks for the reply. It still leaves the top header with the menus.alt + f9 hides the bottom '''footer'''. Isn't there a button for hiding the top one? Would scripting of that be complicated ?

Edit2: here's what i would like to hide in the 3d view [image: to remove the top header]

Comment: ...think you misread = F10 is what you should be trying not F9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F10</kbd> = something somebody already thought of. Repeat <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F10</kbd> to exit fullscreen mode.

This is what I get with mouse over default 3D layout ...

[image]

...and as Sambler says once more with <kbd>F11</kbd> and even the Blender bar is hidden.

[image]

Comment: Alt-F11 also makes the window fullscreen - removing the window titlebar.

Comment: Oh I understand now. You must be in the 3d View Full (I was in the customized view) to use the alt + f11 and alt + f10. The shortcuts do not work in other views. However shift + space does not bring up the properties menu.